# Why is the location data different in Move window vs. Transform data dropdown?

Tags: animation, armature, bones

Trying to understand why the movement of a bone on a particular axis is listed differently in two different areas. See screenshot. I've moved Rain's foot forward on the Y axis. Which is shown in the move window bottom left. Yet it shows that I've moved it on the Z axis in the transform dropdown located top right. Can someone explain why this is? Thx.

[image]

Comment: The move location is adding that number to the Previous location, if i have a model on Location 1.5 m, i could use the move menu to type 0.5 and because of that, the Transform location is going to show 2 instead of 0.5 or 1.5. If you are in world 0 and move your object for the first time, then, the numbers will be the same because is 0 + the new location that you move the object

Comment: Emir, thx. I understand that. Curious why the bottom left box is showing her foot had been moved on the Y axis (which is correct) while the top right box is showing that it had been moved on the Z axis. It seems this may have something to do with bone orientation but I am not sure how to understand it fully.